# What's the logic of unix_timestamp function convert the 2-digit format year to 4-digit format year in the Hive?

Tags: date, hadoop, hive

For example, the below hive script

```
select 
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('30-Apr-50', 'dd-MMM-yy'), 'yyyy-MM-dd') as date1,
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('30-Apr-45', 'dd-MMM-yy'), 'yyyy-MM-dd') as date2,
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('30-Apr-35', 'dd-MMM-yy'), 'yyyy-MM-dd') as date3;
```

The result is as below

```
date1       date2       date3
1950-04-30  1945-04-30  2035-04-30
```

What's the logic behind the unix_timestamp function that convert the 2-digit year to 4-digit year? Is there a fix threshold for the 2-digit year when converting it becomes 20**? If there is, what is the threshold? Is there kind of parameter ('Century Break' as real situation) that we can set the century according to some condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Year**:  ...
> For parsing with the abbreviated year pattern ("y" or
> "yy"), SimpleDateFormat must interpret the abbreviated year relative
> to some century.
> It does this by adjusting dates to be within 80 years before and 20 years after the time the SimpleDateFormat instance is created.
> For example, using a pattern of "MM/dd/yy" and a SimpleDateFormat instance created on Jan 1, 1997, the string "01/11/12" would be interpreted as Jan 11, 2012 while the string "05/04/64" would be interpreted as May 4, 1964.
>
> [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

---

```
hive> select current_date;
2017-03-28

-- 20 years after today

hive> select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('37-03-28','yy-MM-dd'));
2037-03-28 00:00:00

hive> select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('37-03-29','yy-MM-dd'));
1937-03-29 00:00:00

-- 80 years before today

hive> select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('37-03-29','yy-MM-dd'));
1937-03-29 00:00:00

hive> select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('37-03-28','yy-MM-dd'));
2037-03-28 00:00:00
```

---

#### Code walk-through

[hive/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/generic/GenericUDFUnixTimeStamp.java](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/ff67cdda1c538dc65087878eeba3e165cf3230f4/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/generic/GenericUDFUnixTimeStamp.java)

```
public class GenericUDFUnixTimeStamp extends GenericUDFToUnixTimeStamp {
...

public Object evaluate(DeferredObject[] arguments) throws HiveException {
    return (arguments.length == 0) ? currentTimestamp : super.evaluate(arguments);
  }
```

[hive/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/generic/GenericUDFToUnixTimeStamp.java](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/ff67cdda1c538dc65087878eeba3e165cf3230f4/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/generic/GenericUDFToUnixTimeStamp.java)

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
...

public class GenericUDFToUnixTimeStamp extends GenericUDF {
...
  private transient final SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(lasPattern);
...
  public Object evaluate(DeferredObject[] arguments) throws HiveException {
...
        retValue.set(formatter.parse(textVal).getTime() / 1000);
...
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, it clear my doubts perfectly. For unix_timestamp function, is there a way to change the "80 years before and 20 years after" time window? For example, change to "50 years before and 50 years after"

Comment: You're welcome. It doesn't seem like the cut-off date can be changed.